# How do I update a scope attributes in the link method?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

This code is just a test that I'm putting together so I can understand the logic. 
Basically what I want to happen is to get a value passed into the directive. Based on that value, I want to add several attributes to the scope.

This first test is just to update the attribute that was already passed in.

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('bd.common')

    .directive('bdPopoverLegend', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                legendInfo: '=info'
            },
            templateUrl: '/bd/common/ctl/bdPopoverLegend.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.legendInfo.test = 'hello world 4';
            }
        };
    });
```

**Template:**

```
<div>{{legendInfo.test}}</div>
```

**Calling the Directive:**

```
<div bd-popover-legend="" info="{test: 'hello world 3'}">
```

The value never changes, it stays as 'hello world 3' and not 'hello world 4'

Comment: Just do not pass constants to '=' binding. Change it to '&' and your example will work. or pass scope variable that is {test: ...}

Comment: I'm not understanding, can you show me an example?  Also, ultimately, I want to add properties to the scope to be used in the directive.  Would this still apply?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GsQjHYfJFKJxSyUe6wJC?p=preview this is usual use of bindings. If you want to do it another way - it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.directive('bdPopoverLegend', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            legendInfo: '=info'
        },
        templateUrl: '/bd/common/ctl/bdPopoverLegend.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.$watch('legendInfo', function (watchInfo) {
              watchInfo.test = 'hello world 4';
          });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: ok right you dont need to write scope inside it. I will update the answer

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an ng-repeat.  Anyway, I get an error that 10 $digest() interations reached. Aborting!

Comment: Also, I don't necessarily have to update the value, it would also work if I created a new attributes.  like `test2`

Comment: mostly `$digest` comes only when you use `$apply()`. so may be it is comming from some other part of code, first make confirm that you are getting value in `watchInfo.test` by ading console

Comment: I've confirmed that `watchInfo.test` has the value